# Hibernate 4 -- configuring C3P0

Tags: hibernate, c3p0

I would not have posted this unless I was truely frustrated. I am trying to configure C3P0 with Hibernate 4.1.1 in a very simple application but I am getting a class not found exception. I have included C3P0 specific jar file in my classpath. hibernate-c3p0-3.5.2-Final.jar

hibernate.properties:

```
hibernate.connection.provider_class=org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment=1
hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period=180
hibernate.c3p0.max_size=60
hibernate.c3p0.max_statements=0
hibernate.c3p0.min_size=10
```

Stacktrace:

```
28 Jul, 2012 9:23:08 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider
INFO: HHH000130: Instantiating explicit connection provider: org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:150)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2277)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2273)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1742)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1782)
    at eko.test.hibernate.Hibernate4Test.main(Hibernate4Test.java:17)
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not instantiate connection provider [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:114)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.initiateService(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:176)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider]
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.ConnectionProviderInitiator.instantiateExplicitConnectionProvider(ConnectionProviderInitiator.java:189)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$1.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:99)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.service.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:138)
    ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The jar file you included has the version 3.5.2-Final, and doesn't contain the class you configured. Why don't you use the one which has the version 4.1.1 (since this is the version of Hibernate that you use), and which has the necessary class inside: http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0/4.1.1.Final/

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not sure why this jar file is not included with the 4.1.1 hibernate bundle I downloaded from the web site.

Comment: I just looked at the download bundles and they all contain the hibernate-c3p0 jar.  Not sure what "hibernate bundle" you are looking at...